# Getting column names of a query in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to get only columns names of a query result without the need of running all the query.
for example, if table a columns are: `id, price, txn_date,city_id` and table b columns are: `city_id,city_name, country`

I want a query that will output only column names of the following query:

```
Select a.*,b.* from a left join b on a.city_id=b.city_id
```

**without using CPU to compute all the results.**

desired output:
`id, price, txn_date, city_id, city_name, country`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add  condiniion ever false  and use an inner join

```
Select a.*,b.* from a inner join b on a.city_id=b.city_id and 1= 2
```

this should return a result without rows

or dorectly

```
Select a.*,b.* from a inner join b on  1= 2
```

Comment: But will it use a lot of CPU for this? I have some heavy queries..

Comment: answer updated ..  without columns in ON clause .. ..(anyway without using CPU .. with a compute  .. is not possible)